# StreamBuilder is duplicating newly added documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream with infinite list which fetches records when last item is reached to the bottom and also newly created documents to the top. which is working correctly.

Now, When new document is created the top element is duplicated twice.

Now, to tackle this solution I am thinking to remove `with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<InboxScreen>` which will refresh the screen upon screen change but this costs much more in long term. Kindly help.

```
class InboxScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const InboxScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<InboxScreen> createState() => _InboxScreenState();
}

class _InboxScreenState extends State<InboxScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<InboxScreen> {
  static String className = 'InboxScreen';
  final log = Logger();
  StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _streamController =
      StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>();
  late List<DocumentSnapshot> _answers = [];

  bool _isRequesting = false;
  bool _isFinish = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('answers')
        .where('toUserRef',
            isEqualTo: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid))
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => onChangeData(data.docChanges));

    requestNextPage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent == scrollInfo.metrics.pixels) {
            requestNextPage();
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
          stream: _streamController.stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) return SomeThingWentWrongWidget();
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: LoadingWidget(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text("No messages yet!"),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text("No messages yet!"),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                // separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                //   color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                // ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  AnswerModel answer = AnswerModel.fromJson(
                      snapshot.data![index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
                  answer.id = snapshot.data![index].id;
                  String answerId = snapshot.data![index].id;
     
                  return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
               
                      },
                      child: InboxLineItemWidget(answer));
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void requestNextPage() async {
    //checking if stream is closed
    if (_streamController.isClosed) return;

    //checking if already loading or no more data
    if (!_isRequesting && !_isFinish) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
      _isRequesting = true;
      if (_answers.isEmpty) {
        querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('answers')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .where('toUserRef',
                isEqualTo: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid))
            .limit(10)
            .get();
        log.d("querySnapshot: ${querySnapshot.docs}");
      } else {
        //get document from the last of the list
        querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('answers')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .where('toUserRef',
                isEqualTo: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid))
            .startAfterDocument(_answers[_answers.length - 1])
            .limit(10)
            .get();
      }

      if (querySnapshot != null) {
        int oldSize = _answers.length;
        _answers.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
        int newSize = _answers.length;
        if (oldSize != newSize) {
          _streamController.add(_answers);
        } else if (newSize == 0) {
          _streamController.add(_answers);
        } else {
          _isFinish = true;
        }
      }
      _isRequesting = false;
    }
  }

  void onChangeData(List<DocumentChange> documentChanges) {
    var isChange = false;
    documentChanges.forEach((answerChange) {
      if (_answers.any((answer) => answer.id != answerChange.doc.id)) {
          _answers.insert(0, answerChange.doc);
          isChange = true;
      }
      if (answerChange.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
        _answers.removeWhere((answer) {
          return answerChange.doc.id == answer.id;
        });
        isChange = true;
      } else {
        if (answerChange.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
          int indexWhere = _answers.indexWhere((answer) {
            return answerChange.doc.id == answer.id;
          });

          if (indexWhere >= 0) {
            _answers[indexWhere] = answerChange.doc;
          }
          isChange = true;
        }
      }
    });

    if (isChange) {
      _streamController.add(_answers);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget SomeThingWentWrongWidget() {
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Something went wrong"),
    );
  }

  Widget InboxLineItemWidget(AnswerModel answer) {
    //Here is the widget
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you receive a new `QuerySnapshot` from Firestore, that snapshot contains all documents for the query - including any documents that were not changed since the last time you received a snapshot.

So:

- The first time your `onChangeData` runs, it adds all documents to the `_answers` array and it shows up correctly.
- The second  time your `onChangeData` run, it adds all documents again to the `_answers` array. This includes documents that were not modified, so those now shows up twice.
- This continues for any subsequent calls to `onChangeData`.

You have two options to fix the problem:

- The simplest is to clear your `_answers` array before adding the documents to it. So something like:

  ```
  if (querySnapshot != null) {
    answers.clear();
    _answers.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
    _streamController.add(_answers);
  }
  ```
- If you use a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), each `QuerySnapshot` object also contains exact information about what happened to each document since the previous snapshot, so you can also [process only the changes from the previous snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).